# Creating a language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I am given a list languages, say $L$, over alphabet $\{a,b\}$. A function $f$ is defined such that $f(i) = L$ for $i ∈ N$.  I am trying to a construct a language $D$ which is not in the list (aka. $D \neq f(n)$). I am not quite sure how to construct a language,  I started off by constructing a language of $i$ that is not a natural number such as $N = \{-2, -1\}$ but I am not quite if this is correct? What can be concluded from that language?

Comment: Are you familiar with Cantor's diagonal proof that the real numbers are not countable?

Comment: no i am not. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the language $D$ defined by:

1. $D$ contains no word that has a $\mathtt b$ in it.
2. For every $n\in\mathbb N$, the word $\mathtt a^n$ (that is, $\underbrace{\mathtt{aaa\ldots a}}_{n\text{ a's}}$) is in $D$ if and only if it is *not* in $f(n)$.

Can you prove that $D$ is not in the list?

Comment: Hmm. Thats good. I am not sure how to prove it except for the fact that I know since it has no words that has b in it (therefore no in L). How could I prove that? I am a little new to this material not sure about proofs

Comment: @Raj: The way to prove that $D$ is not in the list is to prove that $D\ne f(n)$ for every $n$.

Comment: Right! Could you give me a hint on how to prove it? I am a little confused. For example, how can I prove that a^n is not in f(n)? I need to show that the letters are not in N